# Querying relations in polymorphic relations - Loopback

Tags: database, polymorphism, loopbackjs

I am trying to create a big request for most of the page data. A certain model has polymorphic relations to a few other models, which in turn have normal relations to other models. What I am trying to achieve is fetch those "sub-relations" along with the polymorphic objects. Something like:

```
filter = {
    include: [{
       canvas: {
          points: {
            device: [
              {
                relation: 'chart',
                scope:    {
                  where: {
                    type: 'line',
                  },
                },
              },
              'model',
            ],
          },
        }
      }],
}
```

As displayed under the `device` (which is the polymorphic relation attribute), I also include two relations, `chart` and `model`. Those relations only exist in one type of `device` `chartDevice`, and if the query fetches such rows, it works. However, if the query fetches other types, e.g. `networkDevice`, which does not include such relations, it crashes.

Also, if I try to include a relation specific to `networkDevice`, it doesn't work.

I guess Loopback might not support that in polymorphic relations, but I am curious if there is any workaround that I might have not thought of.